# List box selection with time consuming task that needs to update the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-5.0

I have an application that performs a time consuming task when the user selects an item for a listbox.

When a user selects a show the application will retrieve all the shows information form the tvdb and the display it in the Ui.

The problem occurs when a user quickly changes selection while the show is still loading.

I would like to make it so that a user could change their mind and then make another selection while the first was loading and have that information displayed in the Ui.

I have created a simple demonstration application to show the problem  : [Demo App](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qliih9jj421382/TVShowInfo.zip) .

This is what i tried to do

**List box selection event handler**

```
private  void lb1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string sid = lb1.SelectedItem.ToString();

            try
            {
                LoadSeries(Int32.Parse(sid));
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid series id");
            }
        }
```

**LoadSeries**

```
private void LoadSeries(int _seriesId)
{

    Task<TvdbSeries> series = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        TvdbSeries seriesloaded = null;
        try
        {
            seriesloaded = m_tvdbHandler.GetSeries(_seriesId, TvdbLanguage.DefaultLanguage, true, true, true, true);
        }
        catch (TvdbInvalidApiKeyException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (TvdbNotAvailableException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return seriesloaded;
    }
     );

    series.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
    {
        UpdateSeries(series.Result);
    },
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );

}
```

If a user changes selection quickly the application errors on the line *`seriesloaded = m_tvdbHandler.GetSeries(_seriesId, TvdbLanguage.DefaultLanguage, true, true, true, true);`* and shows this message in the debugger "**WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations.**"

I did find out that it is because I am making a new request before the last one is finished but I have no way of chaining the code in m_tvdbHandler.GetSeries because its functionality comes from library i am using and some one else wrote .

This is the library [tvdblib](https://code.google.com/p/tvdblib/) , I am sure the problem is with how I am doing things and not the library .

Comment: Couldn't you just create new `TvdbHandler` for each request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting this question as a **C#5.0** question, so you should be using `async`/`await` as much as you can.

```
private Task<TvdbSeries> LoadSeriesAsync(int _seriesId)
{

    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        TvdbSeries seriesloaded = null;
        try
        {
            seriesloaded = m_tvdbHandler.GetSeries(_seriesId, TvdbLanguage.DefaultLanguage, true, true, true, true);
        }
        catch (TvdbInvalidApiKeyException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (TvdbNotAvailableException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return seriesloaded;
    }
     );
}
```

It would be much better if there was a `LoadSeriesAsync`.

One way to do it would be to disable **lb1** while retrieving the series.

private async void lb1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string sid = lb1.SelectedItem.ToString();

```
try
{
    lb1.IsEnabled = false;
    var series = await LoadSeriesAsync(Int32.Parse(sid));

    UpdateSeries(series);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid series id");
    lb1.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

}

Comment: I got to erros when trying this lbl.Enabled = false; -- Error The name 'lbl' does not exist in the current context and Task<TvdbSeries> series = await Task.Run(() => -- The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TvdbLib.Data.TvdbSeries>>'.

Comment: I then try I changed the the LoadSeriesAsync to be  private async Task<TvdbSeries> LoadSeriesAsync(int _seriesId). But this gave me a new error -- Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'TvdbLib.Data.TvdbSeries' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TvdbLib.Data.TvdbSeries>'

Comment: Still get errors on this line ` Task<TvdbSeries> series = await Task.Run(() =>{` saying **Cannot implicitly convert type 'TvdbLib.Data.TvdbSeries' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TvdbLib.Data.TvdbSeries>'** and an error on this line `return series;` saying **Error 2 Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type 'TvdbLib.Data.TvdbSeries' rather than 'Task<TvdbLib.Data.TvdbSeries>'** I have upladed my project to :  https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qliih9jj421382/TVShowInfo.zip if you want to take a look .ps thanks for the help so far

Comment: Sorry. Bad copy+paste. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks got it to work now, I have noticed though that after a certain amount of task are created the UI locks up until some tasks are finished ,so may be i should look at queuing  task may be 3 tasks at a time and if the users selects a 4th show it should cancel task 3 if its still going or has not started and add a new task in its place. Have no idea how to do that yet or even if its a godd idea so will have to research.

Comment: The UI must be blocking because of `UpdateSeries`. Does it really make sense to have 3 tasks running? shouldn't any new request cancel any pending one?

Comment: Ye may be I should do it that way then do you know the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

when a user makes a selection you can disable the UI till the information is loaded completely and display a message at the bottom loading please wait. Once everything is loaded, enable the Ui and hide the message.

Comment: I did think about doing that but it wont make for a very good user experience

Comment: In that case then you can queue users selection and updated it one by one, or if it is possible to stop the current operation, stop it and start the new fresh thread

Comment: How would i do that ?